# I Can't Access Objects After "run()" Method

Tags: java, swing

I am using NetBeans to create this program.
I use MyMain to create a JForm using FrameDemo.
Then I add a JPanel (SensorUI SensorLL=new SensorUI) to the JForm.
(Note I simplified this a little, I actually add four instances of the JPanel.)

The Panel includes a Label "Sensor".

Ultimately my program will be running a timer and once a second it will sample a sensor and display the sampled value in the Sensor Label.

I have a method in Sensor called write(value) that will write (value) in Sensor.

My problem is the creation of the Panel was placed in a "run()" method by NetBeans (I assume).  I can:
`Sensor.write("xxx");` Successfully if it is inside the run() curlys,
but if  I place the 
`Sensor.write("xxx");`
outside the run curlys I get

> cannot find symbol
>   symbol: variable Sensor
>   location: class MyMain

My code is below.  I removed a lot of unnecessary information, I hope not too much.
Each class is in a separate NetBeans class file if that means anything.
For some reason when I look at the preview there is shading that causes early lines of the classes to not be in the shading.  I don't know if the final post will come out that way.  If so, sorry.

```
public class MyMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            FrameDemo.createAndShowGUI();
            SensorUI SensorLL=new SensorUI("SensorLL");
            FrameDemo.addObject(SensorLL);
            SensorLL.writeSensor("xxx");//<<<<<This is OK
        }
    }
    );

            SensorLL.writeSensor(SensorLL, "xxx");//<<<This is not
}
```

---

```
public class FrameDemo {

  /**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
static        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BrewTool");  

public FrameDemo(){

}
static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);

}
static void addObject(SensorUI Sensor){
    frame.add(Sensor);

}
}
```

---

```
public class SensorUI extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form SensorUI
 */
public SensorUI(String title) {
    initComponents();
    Temperature.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
```

A whole lot of NetBeans "Generated Code" removed from this listing
The Jpanel includes a JLabel named "Sensor"

```
public void writeSensor(String value){
    Sensor.setText(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared the variable 'SensorLL' in the wrong scope:

```
public class MyMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Declare it in the main-method
    SensorUI SensorLL = null;

    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            FrameDemo.createAndShowGUI();

            // Here you can simply initialize it, because it's
            // already declared
            SensorLL=new SensorUI("SensorLL");
            FrameDemo.addObject(SensorLL);
            SensorLL.writeSensor("xxx");//<<<<<This is OK
        }
    }
    );

    // Works perfectly fine, because SensorLL is declared
    // outside the run-method
    SensorLL.writeSensor(SensorLL, "xxx");//<<<This is not
}
```

You can't access it from outside the run-method, because in your code it only exists inside the run-method.

**EDIT**
I tried to change your SensorUI class to get the wished behaviour. I came up with this

```
public class SensorUI extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private Thread updateThread = null;
private boolean updateThreadIsRunning = false;

/**
 * Creates new form SensorUI
 */
public SensorUI(String title) {

    // I can't figure out what those do (mainly because of missing source code).
    initComponents();
    Temperature.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));

    // Create a Thread in each SensorUI which is started once the Component is
    // created and then updates the JLabel Sensor each second
    // Now each SensorUI has its own Thread which keeps updating the content of
    // the corresponding JLabel

    this.updateThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

                updateThreadIsRunning = true;

                while(updateThreadIsRunning){
                    // The message which is shown on the Sensor JLabel
                    writeSensor("xxx");
                    try{
                        // Here you can change the update intervall in milliseconds
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

        }
    });

    this.updateThread.start();

}

// Here are the leftout lines

public void writeSensor(String value){
    Sensor.setText(value);
}
}
```

If i got you right, this should exactly do what you want. I wasn't able to test the code because of the missing classes so if find any mistakes just say something and i'll try to update the code accordingly.

Comment: Yes this code will compile and run. but I think the output may be different from the desired one. Because the last line will be executed before the one from inside the run() method. (At least it MAY be executed earlier)

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach you are right. I don't exactly know what the intentional idea was, but i thought the question was meant like "why can't I use the writeSensor method here?".

Comment: Yes your answer is absolutely correct. But I think this answer will lead to more questions, like "Why can't I see the correct value?".

Comment: I get:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at my.myprogram2.MyMain.main(MyMain.java:45) at the second SensorLL.......  As I said after these SensorUIs are created I want to start an timer that reads a sensor and displays the result in the Sensor JLabel.  I tried starting the timer inside the run() but that throws lots of errors.  I can't seem to find a way to keep SensorLL alive.

Comment: Did you remove the initialization of the SensorLL inside the run method?

Comment: I tried that before and the JPanels don't get generated.  I am going to try and leave it "hung" in run() with while (true) after starting the timer.

Comment: Could you update the problem with an exact describtion of your error and what you did?

Comment: OK.
(1) When I do as you suggest and put "SensorUI SensorLL = null;" before the javax I get a warning at the SensorLL.wr...that says "Dereferencing null pointer".  when I run the program I get an output "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at my.myprogram2.MyMain.main(MyMain.java:[the line with the warning)"

(2) As Christian K. points out, it seems to run before the addObject.

(3) I removed the SensorUI SensorLL... from run() and put it later but still within javax.swing... but that doesn't help, still the Exception.
 [Continued]

Comment: (4) My problem is I need to create the JForm like happens within run() but I need to be able to access its contents after that.  I don't know what run() does or why I need it.  NetBeans created it.  It has something to do with multiple threads but I get lost trying to understand that.

Comment: New development.  I moved the lines

Comment: SensorUI SensorLL=new SensorUI("SensorLL");
FrameDemo.addObject(SensorLL); to before the javax.swing and now the SensorLL.writeSensor("sss"); at the end of main works.  Then I start a timer.  Then I need to get something like SensorLL.writeSensor("sss"); working in the timer class.

Comment: To do that I think I will have to take their suggestion and 'autimatically move this discussion to chat"  I hope the thread surives.  Thanks

Comment: Oops, I "have only one reputation, not enough to chat".  I guess I'll have to do it over many comments.

Comment: Explaination. (Before I edited my listing to show only one sensor. 
From now on I will have four sensors just in case.)

I have a JFrame with two JPanels, SensorLL, SensorLC, SensorCR and SensorRR. 
They are instances of the class Sensor.  
Each has a JLabel called Sensor.
I will have a timer that will run once a second.  
Once a second I will read the sensors and display the result in the
Jlabel "sensor" in each jPanel.

I have not started the Sensor reading code yet.

Comment: I use MyMain to call FrameDemo and create the JFrame and a method
in FrameDemo to add the JPanels using addObject.

With the code for doing the above inside the run() where NetBeans put it
I could not write to the Sensor JLabel in the SensorLL panel using a method writeSensor in SensorLL.
I moved the code for doing the above from inside run() to before 
run() and now the SensorLL.writeSensor will write text to JLabel Sensor 
in Sensor while in Mymain.
Then I start the timer ReadSensor.
For an experiment I try to write to the JLabel while in the timer routine
it won't work.

Comment: I'll try to find a way to post the code. Right now i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I eddited my answer and change the SensorUI class